# How to remove Save and Continue button from edit view all module in Sugarcrm 7

Tags: sugarcrm

How to remove the "Save and Continue" and the pagination button(marked in image) from edit view of all the modules in sugarcrm 7? [image]

Comment: I found that adding configuration `$sugar_config['disable_vcr'] = true;` in `config_override.php` file will disable these buttons in both Detailview and Editview. But i need to disable only in EditView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To remove only in Edit View of all modules**

Override the file `"include\EditView\SugarVCR.tpl"` by copy and  paste at `"custom\include\EditView\SugarVCR.tpl"` and change the logic.

I added `{if empty($list_link)}` as per my need.

**To hide from all the view of all the modules**

Add a new configuration `$sugar_config['disable_vcr'] = true;` in `config_override.php` file